# Command Line Parameters in Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I am using a program called sonar-runner that you execute from the commandline, and you can pass optional parameters. For example in the normal windows commandline tool a call may look something like:

```
sonar-runner -Dsonar.dryRun=true -Dsonar.inclusions=src/main/java/com/schoen/Test.java
```

When I try running that same command from Powershell I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Unrecognized option: .dryRun=true
INFO:
INFO: usage: sonar-runner [options]
INFO:
INFO: Options:
INFO:  -D,--define <arg>     Define property
INFO:  -e,--errors           Produce execution error messages
INFO:  -h,--help             Display help information
INFO:  -v,--version          Display version information
INFO:  -X,--debug            Produce execution debug output
```

It is essentially parsing the parameters incorrectly, breaking them appart on periods instead of spaces. Is there away to work around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap them in quotes so that powershell does not try to parse it:

```
sonar-runner.exe "-Dsonar.dryRun=true" "-Dsonar.inclusions=src/main/java/com/schoen/Test.java"
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick for the most part. I had to wrap each `-D...` section in quotes for it to work. I suggested an edit to indicate that in your answer.